# concatenating multiple files into groups of files

Tags: bash

I am rather new to BASH scripting and need some help.

I am attempting to concatenate 312 files into 39 groups of files which have rather awful filenames to work with. The series of files for one group looks like:

> C9F4BANXX-1959-01-21-01_L003_R1.fastq
>
> C9F4BANXX-1959-01-21-01_L004_R1.fastq
>
> C9F4BANXX-1959-01-21-01_L005_R1.fastq
>
> C9F4BANXX-1959-01-21-01_L006_R1.fastq

to concatenate this group I use the following (very clunky I am sure - but it works):

```
cat *-01-*_*_R1.fastq > 01_R1.fastq
```

The files differ in the 3rd string in the name (in bold) i.e.

> C9F4BANXX-1959-**01**-21-01_L003_R1.fastq
>
> C9F4BANXX-1959-**02**-21-01_L003_R1.fastq

I am struggling to get my head around how to set up a loop to iterate the concatenation for each group of 4 files based on the position indicated in the file name

Thanks for the help

Comment: Using cat and wildcards is not clunky at all, in fact it is probably the most efficient(within reason) way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly you can use a for loop.

You can use seq in a subshell to pad the numbers.

```
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" 1 39);do cat *-"$i"-*_*_R1.fastq > "$i"_R1.fastq ;done
```

Comment: Many thanks for that - I was struggling to put the various bits of the 'for' loop together to work only on the central part of the string.

Comment: Just explored more about the seq command and the format you used - very cool! Thanks again - this is a great tool to use for other jobs I have